# Styling Select elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have been searching online for custom styling of  elements ( drop down box ) in html and not getting much help apart from Jquery plugins. I did noticed through firebug that this site: http://themeforest.net/user/freshface/portfolio is doing some sort of ul list above it and using display none to elements to hide and show accordingly.

I'm using firebug to go through the html page from the link above but still can't find if they are using JS to control all the hiding and showing. Am I over analyzing this and there is a much simpler approach. All I'm trying to achieve is a similar look and design to the drop down select element on the link above site above.

Answer (score 2):

They are indeed using js/jQuery.

Look for `jqTransform` in http://1.envato-static.com/javascripts/envato.min.js?1310371894

Comment: I see it now thanks. What I'm not getting as its hard to read because of the minify renaming all the variables to shorthand is what they are hiding. It looks like from the code they are using a ul list above the select options tag. Now when the user selects a a tag inside the li is this entire list getting hidden and they are doing a search for the li selected index and then setting the <select> component to that index.

Answer (score 0):

This type of style is done completing a ul>li with "select" data via js and the styling using css. :)

Comment: Can you elaborate more. or maybe you know of a tutorial online using this style of implementation.

Comment: See this link: http://info.wsisiz.edu.pl/~suszynsk/jQuery/demos/jquery-selectbox/ ;)